# change ldap user password from web based client

Tags: linux, active-directory, fedora, openldap

I am able to change password by connecting ldap server using fedora-idm-console with admin user   of every user .But Every user  needs to change their password by connecting server remotely  using web server client Like phpldapadmin. But when a user connect to server to change password only he can see his details only .

Can you please help me .

Comment: The recommended security settings for openldap permits the change of passwords of all users by the `admin` user, and only change your own password as any other user.

Comment: Thanks,can you please tell me ,how users can change their password remotely .

Comment: If you're using linux/unix with user accounts via LDAP then the `passwd` command should work. You can use the `ldappasswd` command to manually change the password also - http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldappasswd

Comment: then every user should know these commands , Is there any way ,to change password and details by login to a simple web client

Comment: a 5 minute google search reveals - http://technology.mattrude.com/2010/11/ldap-php-change-password-webpage/

Comment: Thanks , i will check and Let you know

Comment: Thanks ,That script is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

by default ldap user does not have any privileges in database, even can't read and authentificate it. if you would like to every user able to change their password, you have to allow this in slapd.conf (or slapd.d). here is my configuration to allow changing own password and some personal attributes:

```
access to attrs=userPassword
 by dn="uid=root,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by group/groupOfNames/member.exact="cn=ldapadmins,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by self write
 by anonymous auth
 by * none

access to attrs=
  mail,
  sn,
  givenName,
  telephoneNumber,
  mobile,
  facsimileTelephoneNumber,
  street,
  postalAddress,
  postOfficeBox,
  postalCode,
  roomNumber,
  shadowLastChange,
  ldapPublicKey,
  sshPublicKey,
  sambaLMPassword,
  sambaNTPassword,
  sambaPwdLastSet 
 by dn.base="uid=root,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by group/groupOfNames/member.exact="cn=ldapadmins,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by self write
 by * read

access to *
 by dn="uid=root,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by group/groupOfNames/member.exact="cn=ldapadmins,dc=domain,dc=tld" write
 by * read
```